# sudoku solver, get the boxes to point to the right tile

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, sudoku

I am writing a sudoku solver and I have been stuck for several hours now, I just can't get it to work.

The solver can take in any sized board up to 64 tiles, and the boxes can be any rectangular shape. I have created the boards and created all the tiles in a two-dimensional array so that part is all right. The problems occur when I want to place the same tiles in their box.

```
 0 -> 0 1 0 | 0 0 4 <- 1
      0 0 0 | 8 0 0 
      ------------- 
 2 -> 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 <- 3
      1 0 0 | 2 7 0
      ------------- 
 4 -> 0 0 0 | 9 0 0 <- 5
      0 2 0 | 0 0 0
```

So a board like this, the boxes are numbered as shown above, from left to right. And the tiles are numbered like this:

```
tile[row][column]
```

e.g: The "4" in the top right corner is tile[0][5] on the board.

So now to the problem at hand. The boxes has a two-dimensional array sized like the box, and every array should point at the right tile on the board. The board and the boxes are already created, I just need the box's array to point to the right tile on the board.

e.g: Box number "3" should have two-dimensional array with six values being:

```
[0][0] = 0; [0][1] = 0; [0][2] = 1;
[1][0] = 2; [1][2] = 7; [1][3] = 0;
```

I have tried a lot of for-loop nesting, but I can't get it to pick the right tiles for every given scenario. The sudoku board given can be any size with boxes shaped in any rectangular form.

Edit: The code I have written, it's norwegian-based, ask if anything is unclear.

Edit2: The problem is located in the last method of the Brett-class.

```
class SudokuSolver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Brett sudoku = lesFil(args[0]);



    }

    //Creates the sudoku board from a txt-file.
    public static Brett lesFil(String filnavn) throws Exception {
        Scanner fil = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
        String linje = "";

        int antRad = Integer.parseInt(fil.nextLine());
        int antKol = Integer.parseInt(fil.nextLine());
        int antBoks = 0;
        //antall Bo(kser), Ra(der) og Ko(lonner)
        int antBoRaKo = antRad * antKol;
        Brett nyttBrett = new Brett(antBoRaKo, antRad, antKol);
    nyttBrett.bokser[antBoks] = new Boks(antBoRaKo);

        for(int i = 0; fil.hasNextLine(); i++) {
            if(i == antRad) {
        antBoks++;
                nyttBrett.bokser[antBoks] = new Boks(antBoRaKo);
            }
            linje = fil.nextLine();

            for(int j = 0; j < linje.length(); j++) {
                if(j == antKol) {
            antBoks++;
                    nyttBrett.bokser[antBoks] = new Boks(antBoRaKo);
                }

                Rute nyRute = new Rute(tegnTilVerdi(linje.charAt(j)));
                nyttBrett.ruter[i][j] = nyRute;
                nyttBrett.bokser[antBoks-1].ruter[i][j] = nyRute;
            }
        }

        return nyttBrett;
    }

    //Sign to value.
    //Gikk utifra at 0 skal representere en tom rute.
    public static int tegnTilVerdi(char tegn) {
        if (tegn == '.') {
            return 0;
        } else if ('1' <= tegn && tegn <= '9') {    // tegn er i [1, 9]
            return tegn - '0';
        } else if ('A' <= tegn && tegn <= 'Z') {    // tegn er i [A, Z]
            return tegn - 'A' + 10;
        } else if (tegn == '@') {                   // tegn er @
            return 36;
        } else if (tegn == '#') {                   // tegn er #
            return 37;
        } else if (tegn == '&') {                   // tegn er &
            return 38;
        } else if ('a' <= tegn && tegn <= 'z') {    // tegn er i [a, z]
            return tegn - 'a' + 39;
        } else {                                    // tegn er ugyldig
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

//Board-class where I am trying to match the boxes with the board.
class Brett {
Rute[][] ruter;
Boks[] bokser;
//antall bokser, antall rader og kolonner i hver boks.
int antBoks, antRad, antKol;

Brett(int antBoks, int antRad, int antKol) {
    ruter = new Rute[antBoks][antBoks];
    bokser = new Boks[antBoks];
    this.antBoks = antBoks;
    this.antRad = antRad;
    this.antKol = antKol;
}

//My last try of many, probably not my best try.
public void ruterIBoks2() {
    int cntRad = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < antBoks; k++) {
        int cntKol = 1 * k;
        for(int i = 0; i < antRad; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < antKol; j++) {
                bokser[i][j] = ruter[cntRad][cntKol - 1];
                cntKol++;
            }
            cntRad++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code and point to exactly where the problem is in the current code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may come from the `cntKol` variable in your `ruterIBoks2` method.

You set it at `k * 1` (where you could just set it to k), which is equal to 0 at first, since it's your `for` condition.

The trouble is that you want to access the `cntKol - 1`th element in your array.

`bokser[i][j] = ruter[cntRad][cntKol - 1];`

Or in other terms the -1th element, which is probably the cause of your trouble.